# in qt how can i run two query sucessfully?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

How can I run two query  if I run one query is executed successfully then  the second query must also be executed else the value changed by first query should be reverted?

```
QSqlQuery *query=new QSqlQuery(connector.db);

QSqlQuery *query2=new QSqlQuery(connector.db);
```

here both  query and query 2 should run or none query should run.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a [transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). Using the following code, you can ensure that either both of them or none of them will be executed.

```
QSqlDatabase::database().transaction();

// execute your queries here!    

QSqlDatabase::database().commit();
```

[Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/sql-sqlstatements.html):

> If the underlying database engine supports transactions, `QSqlDriver::hasFeature(QSqlDriver::Transactions)` will return `true`. You can use `QSqlDatabase::transaction()` to initiate a transaction, followed by the SQL commands you want to execute within the context of the transaction, and then either `QSqlDatabase::commit()` or `QSqlDatabase::rollback()`. When using transactions you must start the transaction before you create your query.